# Simple Image Gallery on Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I have created a new orchard site on Azure Websites. I would like to add image gallery functionality to the home page.

This is what I did:

1. Installed the nwazet ZenGallery module
2. Created a new content type and called it 'Zen Gallery Type'
3. Added Zen Gallery Part to the 'Zen Gallery Type'
4. Selected Widgets from the Orchard Admin menu
5. Tried to add 'Zen Gallery Type' to the AsideSecond zone

I was then presented with the following error message - can anyone please let me know what I did wrong?

```
Oops. Something went wrong ... sorry
An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back
Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentCreateExtensions.New[T](IContentManager manager, String contentType) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\ContentExtensions.cs:line 19 at Orchard.Widgets.Controllers.AdminController.AddWidget(Int32 layerId, String widgetType, String zone, String returnUrl) at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__10() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the module is not running on Azure. Please file a bug here: https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/nwazet.zengallery/issues/new

With Orchard 1.7 out however, I would recommend not using the module at all, and instead use the built-in media library field configured for multiple images.